# What happens to documents and subcollections in a deleted collection?

Tags: firebase

Let's say that I have a collection with 5 documents and I delete that collection directly from the Firebase Console... do all the documents and nested collections are deleted too?

If the answers is yes... this behavior is only when doing it directly from the Console? Or is it possible from the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I delete that collection directly from the Firebase Console... do all the documents and nested collections are deleted too?

YES. All their documents and its subcollections will get removed in a click. Please refer the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/using-console#delete_data)!

> this behaviour is only when doing it directly from the Console?

You could do it using Firebase SDK as well, like mentioned below.

> is it possible from the SDK?

Yes it is possible; but, you cannot achieve it with single query call. To delete an entire collection or subcollection in Firestore, retrieve all the documents within the collection or subcollection and delete them.

Firestore ref - https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data#collections

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you delete a collection all of its documents and nested collection will get deleted. Also, the deletion can be done directly in the console and from the SDK